# sbt autoplugin: add javaagent for task

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

I have a sbt autoplugin and when the user runs a task I want to fork a new JVM with a -javaagent. The task should measure memory using [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm).

```
object SbtMemory extends AutoPlugin {
    object autoImport {
        val agentTest = inputKey[Unit]("Run task with javaagent")
    }
    def makeAgentOptions(classpath: Classpath) : String = {
            val jammJar = classpath.map(_.data).filter(_.toString.contains("jamm")).head
            s"-javaagent:$jammJar"
        }
    override lazy val projectSettings =
            Seq(
                agentTest := agentTask.value,
                fork in agentTest := true,
                javaOptions in agentTest += (dependencyClasspath in Test).map(makeAgentOptions).value
            )

    lazy val agentTask = Def.task {
        val o = new Array[Byte](1024*1024)
        val mm = new MemoryMeter()
        println("Size of new Array[Byte](1024*1024): " + mm.measureDeep(o))
    }
}
```

When I run `sbt perf` from the command line, I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Instrumentation is not set; Jamm must be set as -javaagent
```

I also tried printing the javaOptions and the `-javaagent` option was not set.

How can I add the `-javaagent` javaOption inside the plugin to run the task with jamm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `fork` is only available for the `run` and `test` task. I added my own forking code and moved the measure code to a separate class `MemoryMeasure`:

```
val mainClass: String = "MemoryMeasure"
val forkOptions = ForkOptions(
    bootJars = (fullClasspath in Test).value.files,
    runJVMOptions = Seq(
        (dependencyClasspath in Test).map(makeAgentOptions).value
    )
)
val process = Fork.java.fork(forkOptions, mainClass +: arguments)
def cancel() = {
    process.destroy()
    1
}
val exitCode = try process.exitValue() catch { case e: InterruptedException => cancel() }
```